# Calling a request in API using php

Tags: php, api, soap, soap-client

I am trying to call a function in API using the method bellow but I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
$wcfClient = new SoapClient('http://apisite.com/FlighSearch.svc?wsdl');
$postData=array(
'username'=>'username',
'password'=>'password'
);
$response = $wcfClient->UserAuthentication($postData);
echo $response->UserAuthenticationResult;
```

I am getting this result:
Authentication Success
its mean API connection is ok. Now I am calling function this way:

```
$response_final = $wcfClient->SearchFareReturnFlight('U',"5HB","12/12/2015","12/30/2015",1,"LHR","HKG","username","password");

echo $response_final
```

But its not working for me please can you check what is the problem ?